# Why won't one out of five web forms/vb.net apps not work in the fortify extension in vs 2022

Tags: visual-studio, web, fortify

Unable to run webform solution in fortify analysis in Visual Studio 2022

I have five apps; most work with analysis, one doesn't.

I am new to fortify. In this case, I'm running fortify inside of Visual Studio 2022 from the Extensions menu. I have five web forms apps; four analyze successfully. One app displays this message in the analysis progress box:

> Unable to load build session with ID "XXXX.sln" (this needs to be obfuscated).

The .sln file mentioned IS the .sln file that is clicked on to bring up the project in Visual Studio. However, it is not the name of the directory where the code resides.

In the error output window, this error appears (Directories are obfuscated for security reasons):

I am dividing this message in two due to the fact that there are differences between the two sections:

1. ASPNETCOMPILER : error 1003: The directory 'C:**********************\XXXXX' doesn't exist.

In this case, XXXXX is again the name of the .sln file mentioned above-the .sln that you click on to bring up the solution in Visual Studio.

2. [C************************\YYYYYYYYY\XXXXX.metaproj]

In this case, YYYYY is the name of the actual directory that the code resides in. XXXXX again is the name of the .sln file.

I did some searches for XXXXX in the directory, but it is in too many places. I tried going into the .sln file and changed the following parameters to the name of the directory the code resides in. They HAD been set to the name of the .sln file described above. I did this for both debug and the release parameters:

```
Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "YYYYYYY"

Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath =  "YYYYYYY"
```

Unfortunately, the analysis threw the same errors as before. Obviously, this "directory" is listed in some file in the code, but I can't tell where it is. As I said, four other similarly structured web forms apps work fine with fortify analysis. All the apps are written in vb.net.

Any help would be appreciated